# LocalStorage Problemas al Eliminar con Clases

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

Tengo el siguiente problema con `localstorage`, estoy trabajando con clases en JavaScript e intento eliminar un dato.

Me sale error siguiente:

> Uncaught TypeError: DeleteCity is not a function at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick

Solo es cuando deseo eliminar un dato, porque en el código de agregar y listar me funciona correctamente.

**Código clase Ciudad**

```
const FormCiudad = document.getElementById("Ciudad");
let tabla = document.getElementById("table");
let agregar = [];

class Ciudad {
  constructor(codigo, ciudad) {
    this.codigo = codigo;
    this.ciudad = ciudad;
  }

  AddCity(City) {
    if (agregar === null) {
      agregar = [];
      console.log(agregar);
    }
    agregar.push(City);
    console.log(agregar);
    localStorage.setItem("usuario", JSON.stringify(agregar));
  }

  ListCity() {
    tabla.innerHTML = "";
    let arrayLista = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("usuario"));
    agregar = arrayLista;
    //tabla.innerHTML += '';
    if (arrayLista === null) {
      console.log("sin datos");
    } else {
      for (let lista of arrayLista) {
        tabla.innerHTML += `
        <tr>
            <td> # </td>
            <td>${lista.codigo}</td>
            <td>${lista.ciudad}</td>
            <td><a class='btn btn-success' style='margin-left:12px' title='Editar'><i class='fas fa-edit'></i><a/> |
                <a class="btn btn-danger" id="DeleteCity" onclick=DeleteCity('${lista.codigo}') title='Eliminar'><i class='fas fa-trash-alt'></i><a/> </td>
        </tr>`;
        // <td><buttom onclick=Editar('${lista.codigo}') type='button' class='btn btn-success'><i class='fas fa-edit'></i></buttom> | <buttom type='button' onclick=DeleteCity('${lista.codigo}') class='btn btn-danger'><i class=' fas fa-trash-alt'></i></buttom></td>
      }
    }
  }

  DeleteCity(codigo) {
    let arrayLista = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("usuario"));
    console.log(codigo);
    let Eliminado = arrayLista.findIndex((e) => e.codigo === codigo);
    if (Eliminado !== -1) {
      arrayLista.splice(Eliminado, 1);
      localStorage.setItem("usuario", JSON.stringify(arrayLista));
    }
  }
}
```

**Evento del botón:**

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const ui = new Ciudad();
  ui.ListCity();
});

FormCiudad.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  let codigo = document.getElementById("codigo").value;
  let ciudad = document.getElementById("ciudad").value;

  const City = new Ciudad(codigo, ciudad);

  City.AddCity(City);
  City.ListCity();
  City.DeleteCity(codigo);
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Tienes un ejemplo que pueda probar? a simple vista se ve correcto

Comment: @DarkFrost   claro este es mi repositorio github.com/jesusTimote/crud_App

Answer (score 0):

Lo único que hay que hacer es meter el método `DeleteCity` dentro de la clase `Ciudad`. Con eso estaría resuelto.

```js
class Ciudad {

  constructor(codigo, ciudad) {
    this.codigo = codigo;
    this.ciudad = ciudad;
  }

  DeleteCity(codigo) {
    let arrayLista = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("usuario"));
    console.log(codigo);
    let Eliminado = arrayLista.findIndex((e) => e.codigo === codigo);
    if (Eliminado !== -1) {
      arrayLista.splice(Eliminado, 1);
      localStorage.setItem("usuario", JSON.stringify(arrayLista));
    }
  }
  // ...
}
```

Código completo de la clase:

```js
class Ciudad {

  constructor(codigo, ciudad) {
    this.codigo = codigo;
    this.ciudad = ciudad;
  }

  DeleteCity(codigo) {
    let arrayLista = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("usuario"));
    console.log(codigo);
    let Eliminado = arrayLista.findIndex((e) => e.codigo === codigo);
    if (Eliminado !== -1) {
      arrayLista.splice(Eliminado, 1);
      localStorage.setItem("usuario", JSON.stringify(arrayLista));
    }
  }

  AddCity(City) {
    if (agregar === null) {
      agregar = [];
      console.log(agregar);
    }
    agregar.push(City);
    console.log(agregar);
    localStorage.setItem("usuario", JSON.stringify(agregar));
  }

  ListCity() {
    tabla.innerHTML = "";
    let arrayLista = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("usuario"));
    agregar = arrayLista;
    //tabla.innerHTML += '';
    if (arrayLista === null) {
      console.log("sin datos");
    } else {
      for (let lista of arrayLista) {
        tabla.innerHTML += `
        <tr>
            <td> # </td>
            <td>${lista.codigo}</td>
            <td>${lista.ciudad}</td>
            <td><a class='btn btn-success' style='margin-left:12px' title='Editar'><i class='fas fa-edit'></i><a/> |
                <a class="btn btn-danger" id="DeleteCity" onclick=DeleteCity('${lista.codigo}') title='Eliminar'><i class='fas fa-trash-alt'></i><a/> </td>
        </tr>`;
        // <td><buttom onclick=Editar('${lista.codigo}') type='button' class='btn btn-success'><i class='fas fa-edit'></i></buttom> | <buttom type='button' onclick=DeleteCity('${lista.codigo}') class='btn btn-danger'><i class=' fas fa-trash-alt'></i></buttom></td>
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: si te das cuenta todo los métodos están dentro de la clase de ciudad, el error es cuando elimino que no detecta el boton del listado y el error Uncaught TypeError: DeleteCity is not a function at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick

Comment: este es el repositorio  github.com/jesusTimote/crud_App

Answer (score 0):

Cuando llamas al método desde el botón eliminar, solo estas llamando a la función con el parámetro, pero como trabajas con clases, debes crear un objeto antes de poder usarlo o en su defecto utilizar uno ya instanciado para poder invocar el método **DeleteCity**.
Por ese motivo te indica el error ***Uncaught TypeError: DeleteCity is not a function at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick*** al darle al botón borrar.

Mi recomendación es que saques el método DeleteCity de la clase y lo pases a una función, con eso debería funcionar.

El código quedaria de la siguiente forma:

```
const FormCiudad = document.getElementById("Ciudad");
let tabla = document.getElementById("table");
let agregar = [];

class Ciudad {
  constructor(codigo, ciudad) {
    this.codigo = codigo;
    this.ciudad = ciudad;
  }

  AddCity(City) {
    if (agregar === null) {
      agregar = [];
      console.log(agregar);
    }
    agregar.push(City);
    console.log(agregar);
    localStorage.setItem("usuario", JSON.stringify(agregar));
  }

  ListCity() {
    tabla.innerHTML = "";
    let arrayLista = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("usuario"));
    agregar = arrayLista;
    //tabla.innerHTML += '';
    if (arrayLista === null) {
      console.log("sin datos");
    } else {
      for (let lista of arrayLista) {
        tabla.innerHTML += `
        <tr>
            <td> # </td>
            <td>${lista.codigo}</td>
            <td>${lista.ciudad}</td>
            <td><a class='btn btn-success' style='margin-left:12px' title='Editar'><i class='fas fa-edit'></i><a/> |
                <a class="btn btn-danger" id="DeleteCity" onclick=DeleteCity('${lista.codigo}') title='Eliminar'><i class='fas fa-trash-alt'></i><a/> </td>
        </tr>`;
        // <td><buttom onclick=Editar('${lista.codigo}') type='button' class='btn btn-success'><i class='fas fa-edit'></i></buttom> | <buttom type='button' onclick=DeleteCity('${lista.codigo}') class='btn btn-danger'><i class=' fas fa-trash-alt'></i></buttom></td>
      }
    }
  }
}

function DeleteCity(codigo) {
    let arrayLista = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("usuario"));
    console.log(codigo);
    let Eliminado = arrayLista.findIndex((e) => e.codigo === codigo);
    if (Eliminado !== -1) {
      arrayLista.splice(Eliminado, 1);
      localStorage.setItem("usuario", JSON.stringify(arrayLista));
    }
  }
```

Y el evento seria:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const ui = new Ciudad();
  ui.ListCity();
});

FormCiudad.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  let codigo = document.getElementById("codigo").value;
  let ciudad = document.getElementById("ciudad").value;

  const City = new Ciudad(codigo, ciudad);

  City.AddCity(City);
  City.ListCity();
  DeleteCity(codigo);
  e.preventDefault();
});
```